# ReactJS How to pass params from child component and router in the same way

Tags: reactjs

Following is the constructor in my react **MainComponent** which receives `id` from the router on passing as `<Link to={"/main/108"}` and the console gives `id: 108`.

```
constructor(props) {
            super(props);  
            this.state = {
                    id: this.props.params.id
            }
            console.log('id: '+id)
    }
```

I have a **ChildComponent** which returns to the **MainComponent** with a param `id` after its functionality as 
`<MainComponent id={this.state.id}/>`. If I have set the state in my constructor as

```
this.state = {
            id: this.props.id
            }
```

will works fine but will gives an error for the `Link` feature.

As this type of parameters should be received as `id: this.props.id` I could not make the constructor working to accept the `id` for both router and child component.

Briefly i just need to set the value of id from both `Link to=` and through ChildComponent.

How can i solve this?

Comment: Your description is very confusing. Can you add more code/description?

Comment: I just made some edits with description. Please check

Comment: You cannot have two values for one variable. If I understand correctly, if ChildComponent pass id (say 100) and link also pass id (say 108), you want id to be 100 not 108. Is this correct?

Comment: No. Both passes value `108`. `<MainComponent id={this.state.id}/>` should be received as `id: this.props.id` inside my constructor. Then it will be an error for `Link to=` method. I need to get value from both stages.

Comment: check out my answer below if that is what you want.

Comment: From my memories, this is `this.props.match.params.id` instead of `this.props.params.id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a OR condition. I.e. if **ChildComponent** passes *id*, use that in state. Otherwise, use the *id* passed by **Link**.

```
this.state = {
   id: props.id || props.params.id
}
```

Comment: This is the logic i'm searching for, but this is not the right way of implementation. I'm getting the error as `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

Comment: You should not get this error. You are passing 'props' as a parameter to the constructor. And why do you think this is not the right way for implementation?

Comment: I just think so as i got the error. But sorry i have given as swaped the props as `props.params.id || props.id` and i got the error. When i tried with `props.id || props.params.id` it does not produces the error.

Comment: id: props.id || (props.params && props.params.id) --> you can use this condition as well. If you do, it wont result in the error